# Valid interconnection of sources?

Tags: power-supply

Im helping with ele homework and and can't seem to come to a conclusion. Here is the circuit. Is this a valid interconnection of ideal sources? Why or why not? I know the two voltage sources by themselves would make it invalid because the voltage sources are not the same magnitude. Does this still apply with a current source?

[image]

Comment: That circuit is valid but meaningless.

Comment: Totally meaningless. I can't even imagine what is it intending to teach.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm confused by the question. It's making my head spin.

Comment: But what is the question posed in her homework?

Comment: The exact question is: Is the following interconnection of sources valid or invalid? That is it. The other questions in the post are out of my own curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. The circuit theory rules here are:

1. Two different ideal voltage sources may not be connected in parallel (across the same pair of nodes).
2. Two different ideal current sources may not be connected in series (in the same branch).

Neither of those rules is broken, so the combination of sources is valid. The circuit obeys KVL, KCL, and conservation of energy.

Putting two voltage sources in parallel violates KVL -- the sum of the voltages around the loop is not zero. Putting two current sources in series violates KCL -- the sum of the currents entering the node between the sources is not zero.